Problems with Updater in python trying to create telegram bot
I have tried reinstalling the libraries but I am still receiving the same error.
I am receiving this error:
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'

This is the code:
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext


TOKEN = 'TOKEN ID from botfather'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    user = update.effective_user
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(
        fr'Hi {user.mention_markdown_v2()}\!',
        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard(),
    )

def main_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("R2SA", callback_data='R2SA'),
         InlineKeyboardButton("BRRR", callback_data='BRRR'),
         InlineKeyboardButton("BTL", callback_data='BTL')]
    ]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def handle_deal_selection(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    context.user_data['deal_type'] = query.data 
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected deal type: {query.data}\n\nPlease enter the description of the deal:")

def handle_description(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    description = update.message.text
    deal_type = context.user_data['deal_type']
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id='-1002022822590', text=f"**{deal_type} Deal**\n{description}")
    update.message.reply_text("Thank you! Your deal description has been posted.")

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Register handlers
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(handle_deal_selection, pattern='^(R2SA|BRRR|BTL)$'))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, handle_description))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I am receiving this error:
(myenv) C:\Users\Anda\Desktop\python>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anda\Desktop\python\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Anda\Desktop\python\test.py", line 5, in main
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'

